# Проявятся ли побочные эффекты многопоточности на машине с одним одноядерным процессором?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Актуальны ли проблемы многопоточности, такие как *race condition* и *false sharing* (других пока не знаю, буду рад, если кто-нибудь подскажет) для машины с одним одноядерным процессором (или если просто рассмотреть все таски конкретного ядра за какой-то промежуток времени)?

Вроде процессор будет по-очереди таски выполнять, кэш-система одна и та жа, все горячие переменные в одних и тех же регистрах. Возникнут ли проблемы?

Comment: Да, такое может быть. Конкретных ссылок не приведу, но буквально пару дней назад читал статью про JMM, где это говорилось прямо. Как минимум реордеринг инструкций может внести свои правки в ход выполнения программы, для одного треда переменная уже установлена, а на самом деле реордеринг сделал так, что этот кусок кода выполнится позже.

Comment: @Etki реордеринг синхронизацией решается. А ключевое слово volatile, получается лишнее, если предположить, что ядро всего одно и не нужна атомарнось операций чтения/записи?

Comment: Нет, там та же ситуация может быть. (Условная) синхронизация по volatile гарантирует вам, что все, что было до этой синхронизации, увидят другие треды (на самом деле это memory barrier, а не синхронизация, и заходить глубже я просто боюсь). В случае отсутствия этой синхронизации (и, конечно, отсутствия внешней синхронизации) реордеринг опять может сыграть свое темное дело. Тред не гарантирует, что его инструкции будут выполнены в той же последовательности, он гарантирует, что они будут производиться с верными значениями.

Comment: Без разницы сколько процессоров. Конкурентность на уровне железа, потоков операционной системы и потоков виртуальной машины - это три разных уровня абстракции. Причём поведение последнего ещё и стандартизировано в JMM, а значит остаётся одинаковым при любых раскладах. Собственно, в середине 90-х, когда JMM и  механизмы многопоточности в Java разрабатывались, подавляющее большинство машин имели один одноядерный процессор.

Answer (score 0):

Актуальны. При выполнении команд допустимы оптимизации. Причем оптимизации идут в рамках одного потока (локальные), и лишь happens before со спецификацией jmm- защита от тех оптимизаций, которые сломают логику Вашей программы в целом. В реальной практике в  отсутствует "глобальный оптимизатор", который видит все потоки и оптимизирует сразу многопоточную программу. Т.е. локальные оптимизации каждого потока, которые противоречат например happens before будут отброшены перед выполнением.

Пример: 
Есть разделяемое поле X = 30; Каждый из двух потоков проверяет значение поля - и 1) первый  если оно больше или равно 40 - добавляет 20, 
2) второй поток если значение больше или равно 50 вычитает 10.

Допустим, при выполнении первого потока локальный оптимизатор сразу решил записать в поле 50 (30+20), а потом, если условие не выполнится, откатить значение обратно в 30. После того как первый заранее туда записал значение 50, пришел второй поток - увидел что там 50 - и пошел по ветке что надо вычесть 10. Первый вернул значение обратно в 30, а второй вычел затем 10 - и получилось 20. 
Ожидаете ли вы такого? Сильно ли помогает то, что одно ядро? Правда в Jmm запрещены значения которые не связаны причинностью по спецификации, но это именно связано со спецификацией,  а не тем,  что есть один процессор